# How can i connect via ssl, https Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, wso2, sails.js

Please, how can i connect via ssl, https Node.js? Here's my code:

```
var Client = require('node-rest-client').Client;
client = new Client();
var headers = {
      //"Accept": "application/json",
      "Authorization": "Bearer "+sails.config.myGlobalVariables.access_token,
    };
    var args = {
      headers: headers,
    };

    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
    client.get("https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid", args, function(data,response) {
      // parsed response body as js object
      //console.log(data.clienteCollection.cliente); //Prueba de listado de clientes recorrer JSON
      // raw response
      //console.log(response);
      //console.log(data.name);
      //req.session.nombreCompleto = data.name;
      //console.log(data);

      res.view('index',{
        nombreCompleto: data.name,
      });
    });
```

I'm using the library node-rest-client and Sails.js.
I do not want to place: process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless you have a chained cert for "localhost", otherwise you have to ignore cert error by NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following [node-rest-client](https://github.com/aacerox/node-rest-client#options-parameters) and [nodejs https.request](https://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_request_options_callback) documentation you could pass your CA in PEM format in options hash when creating a new client. You have to use a chained cert therefore. Otherwise you could use a cert signed by a *well known "root" CA* which is trusted by node.js.

```
new Client({
  connection: {
    ca: fs.readFileSync('ca.pem'),
  }
});
```

As described in [this issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/4175) node.js does not use the operation systems trust store but uses a statically compiled, manually updated, hardcoded list of certificate authorities.